# Maximum pairwise-product of a set in $Z_p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

Let $A$ be a subset of $[1,p-1]$ of size $N$, for a prime $p$.

My question is what is the most efficient algorithm to find: $$\max \{(x \cdot x')~mod~p~|~ x,x'\in A\}$$

In other words, how efficiently can we compute the maximum pairwise-product values for a set $A$ in the field $Z_p$?

Comment: Seems that https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/53161 answers your question (details are explained here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/104818).

Comment: The links consider maximum paiwise sum in integers, I was wondering if something is know for maximum paiwise product in Z_p

Comment: FFT works fine in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this.

As pointed out at the comments, one can obtain the characteristic vector $\chi_{S+T}$ of the multiset
$$S+T = \{s+t \mid s \in S, t \in T\},$$
by defining $\chi_S$ to be the characteristic vector of a set $S$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Then

$$\chi_{S+T} = \chi_S \ast \chi_T,$$

where $\ast$ is the convolution operator. Now using the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$  property gives
$$\mathcal{F}(f\ast g) = \mathcal{F}(f) \times \mathcal{F}(g),$$
where $\times$ represents pointwise multiplication of functions. Thus we have

$$\mathcal{F}(\chi_{S+T}) = \mathcal{F}(\chi_S) \times \mathcal{F}(\chi_T).$$

The Fourier transform is just the complex DFT with length $p.$

Now, let $S_1=A,$ $S_k=S_{k-1} + S_1,$ for $k=2,\ldots,\max(S_1).$ Each one of these operations will be performed in the Fourier domain via
$$\mathcal{F}(\chi_{S_{k-1}+S_1}) = \mathcal{F}(\chi_{S_{k-1}}) \times 
\mathcal{F}(\chi_{S_1}).$$

By carrying out the convolution $\max(S_1)$ times you ensure that you can allow for all the elements of $S_1$ being used as multipliers.

However, you do not want to multiply by elements in the complement of $S_1.$

**Example:** *Let $p=7,$ and $S_1=A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}=\{2,4,5\},$ then you'd perform the convolution 5 times
but you'd want to avoid "multiplying" by 1,3, or 6. A sum of the form
$a_i+a_j$ is valid (2 is in $A$) and can contribute to the maximum, but the single term sum $a_i$ is not (1 is not in $A$), $a_i+a_j+a_k$ is not (3 is not in $A$), etc.*

Note that we can always ignore $0$ even if it is in $A$ since it won't give a maximum value if part of a product.

So what you really want to do now, having computed the $S_k$ is to do the following (recall $S_1=A$):

Let $\textrm{maxprod}=0.$

For $k$ ranging between $1$ and $\max(S_1)$ do:

if $k\in S_1$ (i.e., it is a legitimate multiplier which should be taken into account) then update via
$$
\textrm{maxprod}=\max( \max(S_k), \textrm{maxprod})
$$
$~~~$else don't update.

End do:

Comment: Thanks!
I don't fully understand the time complexity of your method. An N^2 log(p) time algorithm is trivial, I am wondering if this can be improved.

Comment: Usually the FFT based algorithms are not necessarily the most efficient. Since the subset is arbitrary it may not be possible to solve your problem in less than N^2 log p. Without some structure in the set A, One does need to check every pairwise sum.

Comment: My goal was to unpack @Seva’s suggestion. Maybe he can comment if he reads this. There may be a shortcut I am not seeing.

Comment: @kodlu: not much to comment. I agree that it seems unlikely that, in general, one can do this in less than $\Omega(N^2\log p)$ operations, but I cannot rigorously prove this. Maybe, something like $O(|A\cdot A|\log p)$ is possible, but I cannot do this either. I am not sure now that the FFT is of much help (the $O(N\log N)$ bound claimed in the linked MathStackExchange reply does not look realistic).

Comment: @Seva, however it seems to me that $O(N \log N) $ would work if we wanted to find $\max\{ (s+t):s \in S, t \in T\}.$ Do you agree?

Comment: @kodlu: this is quite possible: I was in fact thinking about computing the whole sumset, not just its largest element.

Comment: @Seva,thinking a bit more, wouldn't the computation of the FFT be $O(p \log p)$ ($p$ being the length of ground set where the characteristic function is defined) and N the size of the set is strictly less than $p$? So it may not necessarily be $ O(N \log N)$ I think.